# CountDownTimer been decreses by 2, which should be just 1 sec

Tags: java, android-studio, countdown

I'm creating a quiz game, and there is a countdown timer. But, the countdown decreases by two seconds, which should be just one second. My code is working okay sometimes, but when I install it again, it decreases again in 2 seconds.

```
countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timer, 1200) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {
                timeText.setText(String.valueOf(timeValue));

                timeValue = timeValue - 1;
                if (timeValue == -1){
                    FLAG = 3;
                    playAudio.setAudioforEvent(FLAG);
                    timerDialog.timerDialog();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

                // timerDialog.timerDialog();

            }
        }.start();
```

Comment: Where are you defining this timer? My guess is you're accidentally initialising it twice, then whenever either of the timer ticks down, `timeValue` is changed.

Comment: Oh you're right, did not notice it. Thank you